# Why does Spivak define $f$ to be integrable if $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot |f|$ converges

Tags: calculus, analysis

When Spivak defines integration with partitions of unity on page 65 in Calculus on Manifolds, he states:

"We define $f$ to be integrable (in the extended sense) if $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot |f|$ converges. This implies convergence of $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} |\int_A \phi \cdot f|$ and hence absolute convergence of $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot f$, which define to be $\int_A f$."

He seems to use a stricter condition than necessary, specifically that $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot |f|$ converges. Why does he not broaden the definition of $f$ to be integrable if $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} |\int_A \phi \cdot f|$ converges.

In the latter case, we still have absolute convergence, and since $\int_A \phi \cdot |f| \text{ converges} \implies |\int_A \phi \cdot f| \text{ converges} $, but not necessarily the other way around, we have a broader definition.

Comment: One reason might be is that this condition is exactly what is required for Lebesgue integration of measurable functions.

Comment: What does it mean to you for $\int_A\phi\cdot f$ to converge, if not that $\int_A|\phi\cdot f|=\int_A\phi\cdot|f|$ is finite?

Comment: @Thorgott I'm not sure what you mean. I'm asking about the definition requiring $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot |f|$ to converge (note the summation symbol). Since $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot f$ is the definition of the integral, and it is an infinite sum, to ensure that the sum is well-defined, we require it to be absolutely convergent. But Spivak asks for more, he asks that $\sum_{\phi \in \Phi} \int_A \phi \cdot |f|$ converges, which is a stricter condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partitions of unity are a technical tool that allow us to define integration in a more general setting. As such, we would like $\int_Af=\sum_{\phi\in\Phi}\int_A\phi f$ to depend only on $A$ on $f$, but not on the chosen partition of unity $\Phi$. Indeed, this is the case and the content of Theorem 3-12(1). Try mimicking the proof of this theorem if you only suppose convergence of $\sum_{\phi\in\Phi}\vert\int_A\phi f\vert$ instead of $\sum_{\phi\in\Phi}\int_A\phi\vert f\vert$. You will not be able to do this. Spivak remarks, right between the definition and the theorem, "These definitions do not depend on $\mathcal{O}$ or $\Phi$ (but see Problem 3-38)". Problem 3-38 gives a scenario in which you can find two partitions of unity $\Phi,\Psi$ such that $\sum_{\phi\in\Phi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi f$ and $\sum_{\psi\in\Psi}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\psi f$ both converge absolutely, but to different values. It is instructive to think this through.